# Android XML Layout - Two Columns with rows and one bottom row

Tags: android, xml, layout, row

I'm trying to create a two column layout with rows and one row at the bottom. So far I have achieved two columns with rows in them, but can't seem to figure out how to get the bottom row to show. The following is my code, commented out is how I'm trying to add the bottom row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tracker_id"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="10dp">

<!-- <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"> -->

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/pause_button"
        android:text="@string/pause"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView
        android:text="some text"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView
        android:text="more text"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Bellow is the layout I'm trying to achieve

```
---------------------
|  icon       text  |
|  button     text  |
|  button     text  |
|  icon       text  |
|                   |
|  more more text   |
---------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap everything in a third LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" and add your `TextView` to the bottom of it.

In pseudo-layout:

```
<LinearLayout vertical>
    <LinearLayout horizontal>
        <LinearLayout vertical>
            ... column 1 ...
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout vertical>
            ... column 2 ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is because you want your `TextView` to be **vertically below** your columns.

Comment: So do we put icon, button, button, and icon inside what you labeled "column1". And all the text inside "column2"?

Answer (score 1):

I think Matt answered your question the best, especially if you are just looking for a quick fix.

As B Mac mentions you may find the TableLayout useful and here are two more links that you may find useful.

1. [Layout optimization: Relative Layout](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/)
2. [Debugging and Profiling User Interfaces](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the TableLayout instead of a LinearLayout for the icon/button/text fields that make up your Grid.  You can situate it so it has two columns and however many rows is needed. (If this is not a static arrangement, and you'd want to scroll through the icon/button/text fields as more are added, you may want to consider a ListView layout with user defined layout views...looks like you'd have two here, one with a button and text laid horizontally, and one with an icon and text laid horizontally).

Then, use a horizontal LinearLayout below the TableLayout for the last row with the same width dimenstions as TableLayout defined (looks like you want it to span the two columns you made)?

Comment: I haven't tried the TableLayout, but I do not think it suits my needs and don't plan on scrolling either. The left column is not related to the right column. In my example I just happened to put 4 items in each column. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tracker_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">
<!-- <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"> -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Education/Health"
                android:textColor="#FE9A2E"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tot_val"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$60"
                android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Frequency"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/freq_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Monthly"
                        android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
                 </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Amount"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/amount_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="$20"
                        android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
                 </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Quarterly Amount"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quarter_edit"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="$60"
                        android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quarter_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="$60"
                        android:textColor="#FE9A2E"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        />
                 </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:text="stop"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/pause_button"
        android:text="pause"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">
    <TextView
        android:text="some text"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <TextView
        android:text="more text"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout> -->

<!-- </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-55dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
```